# I'm getting error while POSTing my data on django + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, django-models

I'm using Django + MongoDB. Below I attached my view on Posting my data in User model.

```
def register(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')     
            print(name)       
            email = request.POST.get('email')         
            print(email)
            age = request.POST.get('age')
            print(age)
            qualification = request.POST.get('qualification')
            print(qualification)
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            print(password)
            hashed_password = make_password(password)
            role = request.POST.get('role')
            print(role)
            if role == 'student':
                is_student = True
                is_instructor = False
            if role == 'instructor':
                is_instructor = True
                is_student = False   
            user1 = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
            # print(user1)
            if user1 is not None:
                print(2)
                message = "Email already in used."
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, message)
                return render(request, 'signup.html') 
            user = User(email=email, name=name, age=age, qualification=qualification, password=hashed_password, is_student=is_student, is_instructor=is_instructor) 
            print(user) 
            user.save()
            request.session['email'] = email
            OTP_email(email)
            
            return redirect('otp')
        
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Using multiple print statements I found out while printing user, it printed None. I checked if it's an error from database, maybe User model is not defined but I checked in django shell using hasattr() method, it return True so there is database model name User. Now I'm not able to understand why it is printing None, instead of printing dict or List.

I tried multiple methods to store instance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason None is being output in the given code is that the first() method of User.objects.filter(email=email) returns None when there is no user matching the email.

The code is attempting to search for a user corresponding to the given email address. User.objects.filter(email=email) searches for users with the specified email. The first() method returns the first user in the search results or None if there are no matches.

Therefore, if the user1 variable is not None, meaning there is already a user with that email, it will print "Email already in use." and render the signup.html template.

If user1 is None, indicating that there is no user with that email, the code creates a new instance of the User model, saves it to the database, and proceeds accordingly.

Comment: No I checked and it returned that the user1 is None. The problem here is that when          
user = User(email=email, name=name, age=age, qualification=qualification, password=hashed_password, is_student=is_student, is_instructor=is_instructor) the user is printed None. But problem is I guess User(...) is not building List/Dictionary of the instance that's why the error appeared "Value: None must be of type dict/list".

Comment: I fixed the error. The error is in User model I created a field named course which is JSONField. Because of that it happened. After removing that field, it is running properly.